# Check if optional parameter was provided

Tags: c#

I have a method with an optional string parameter. The default string value for this parameter needs to be created based on one of the other inputs. So I can't define the default value directly in the method parameters. I could set the default value to null and then check for that, however if the string provided was actually null this could create some difficult situations to debug. Is there a way to check if a parameter was actually provided?

```
  public static method(String input1, String input2 = null)
  {
      if (noSecondParameter())
      {
          input2 = getDefaultInput(input1)
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [member overloading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229029%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
public static method(String input1)
{
}

public static method(String input1, String input2)
{
}
```